# Как заставить UIRotationGestureRecognizer работать с одним пальцем?

Tags: swift, swift4

В стандартном варианте **UIRotationGestureRecognizer** работает с двумя пальцами (тапами).

Для работы с одним пальцем, как я понимаю, необходимо эмулировать работу второго пальца в зеркальном отражении относительно центра. 
Вот только как?

Answer (score 1):

Насколько мне известно, никак. Если хотите вращать одним пальцем, то можете сделать свою реализацию на основе `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, вычисляя по координатам прикосновения арктангенс и поворачивая вью с помощью анимации, либо попробовать стороннее решение вроде [этого](https://github.com/MichMich/XMCircleGestureRecognizer)